# Does watch work in Nuxt 3? Watch props in Nuxt 3 not working

Tags: nuxt3

I am trying to watch props in Nuxt 3. But its not working. I couldn't find any topic related to my problem.. Does Watch/watcher working in Nuxt 3?

I want to fill the form fields (which in different component) when I click on update button.

Comment: `its not working` is not really helpful in a debugging-context unfortunately.

Comment: Please add some more context, such as a code snippet or link to a an example where the watcher you're trying to use isn't working, as well any specific error messages or side effects you see.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of context to work off of here, but based on your first sentence:

> I am trying to watch props in Nuxt 3.

I believe you are trying to watch for changes to component properties and have other code run in response to those changes. The functionality you may be looking for here would be the [`toRef` utility that's part of Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities#toref). To quote the docs:

> `toRef()` is useful when you want to pass the ref of a prop to a composable function:

```js
<script setup>
import { toRef } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(/* ... */)

// convert `props.foo` into a ref, then pass into
// a composable
useSomeFeature(toRef(props, 'foo'))

// getter syntax - recommended in 3.3+
useSomeFeature(toRef(() => props.foo))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch props like this  :

```
watch(()=>props.foo, callback)
```